# The idea of smart and dumb components in Elm

Tags: elm

I like React's/Redux' concept of smart and dumb components, where a dumb component does not handle its own state (Dump component does not know anything about the outside world, all it does is triggering an event and displaying value according to its input). This is trivial because all state in handled in one place (main reducer).

In Elm, each component has its own 'update' function (similar to Redux' reducer), so it does not seem trivial to use the same (dumb & smart components pattern).

Is using smart & dump components a good practice in Elm? If so, will I have components without 'update' method? I wonder how will I pass data (props) to my component and how will I trigger events to the parent component.

I will love to hear your thoughts.

Answer (score 4):

The Elm equivalent of a "dumb component" (a.k.a. [Presentational, Pure, Skinny](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0#.189f3fx6p) component) is simply a function that produces `Html`:

```
view : ... -> Html
```

The [elm-html](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/evancz/elm-html/4.0.2/) library is written in this style, e.g.,

```
button : List Attribute -> List Html -> Html
```

You set the "props" by providing attributes when you call the function. In particular, you register events by supplying handlers in `List Attribute`:

```
button
  [ onClick addr ClickAction ]  -- event handler
  [ text "Click me" ]           -- child "components"
```

You'll see this pattern also in other libraries, although the exact types may be different from `List Attribute` and `List Html`.

Answer (score 3):

Another Smart/Dumb distinction you can make is between components that return `Effects` and those that don't. But to answer your question...

Nothing stops you defining actions in a child

```
type Action 
  = Submit
  | Click
```

and in the Parent `view` having

```
Child.view (Signal.forwardTo address ChildAction) props
```

(We pass `props` because there is no model data as such to pass)

but then handling all the actions in the Parent's `update`:

```
case action of 
  ChildAction act ->
    case act of 
      Child.Submit -> 
        ...
      Child.Click -> 
        ...
```

This would be essential anyway if the impact of an Action in Child was to change the state in Parent or some other child of Parent.

Comment: What if you want the child to handle Submit, and parents to handle Click? What does the child's update function look like--in particular, what does it do with Click?

Comment: So,what you are saying is that Child does nothing on a click - i.e. `Click -> model ` (even though this may never in fact be run). The browser won't allow you to leave it unimplemented.

Comment: Imagine a tab that handles the Select message (to add a CSS class) but wishes to let the parent handle the Click message. You're right, Elm won't let you skip the Click pattern match.